# setting tag's value property with json not working

Tags: javascript, json

i have this JS:

```
$.getJSON('getMessageDetails.php', function (json) { 
   var uc = json[4];
   var uc_length = uc.length;
   var firstPartLength = uc_length - 5;
   var uc_1 = uc.substring(0, firstPartLength);  
   var uc_2 = uc.substr(-5, 3);
   var uc_3 = 'RC';
   if (json[2] != old_id)
   {
      $("#td_id").text(json[2]);
      $("#td_id_new").text(json[2]);
      $("#td_subject").text(json[3]);
      $("#span_1").text(uc_1); 
      $("#span_2").text(uc_2); 
      $("#span_3").text(uc_3); 
      old_id = json[2];
   }    
 });
```

then i have my php/html

```
 if (count($row) > 0)
 {
    echo "<input type='hidden' id='td_id_new' value='".$new_id."'></input>";   
    echo  $new_id;
    echo "<tr>";        
    echo '<td><a class="red_link" href="'.ADDRESS.'view_message.php?id='.$new_id.'"><span class="red_link" id="td_subject">'.$subject.'</span></a></td>';
    echo '<td><span id="span_1">'.$uniqueCode1.'</span><span id="span_2" class="pink_text">'.$uniqueCode2.'</span><span id="span_3">'.$uniqueCode3.'</span></td>';
    echo "</tr>";
  }
```

all i want is to set $new_id via my json  $("#td_id_new").text(json[2]);

when i inspect element the output there gives $new_id as 0....as i initialized it and not with the new id everything else(all other tags) updates fine with my json

inspect element:

```
 <input xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" type="hidden" id="td_id_new" value="0">7</input>
```

i got the value property of the above to be 7 thus $new_id is 7 BUT STILL nothing in the a tag for $new_id???

some help please?
thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you set new_id=0 in your PHP.

If you take that out and have initialized the JSON like you said, it should work.

Comment: thank you saw that so i took that out and got the value property of the hidden field to be 7 thus $new_id = 7 but nothing in the <a> tag for $new_id????

Comment: could it be your quotes? They are inconsistent. The input has single quotes inside double quotes and the a tag has double quotes inside of single quotes.

Comment: also ADDRESS looks like it should be $ADDRESS

Comment: ADDRESS is correct as it is...the quotes are also correct..i have the same line in a foreach loop that gets data from the dbtable and no problem there...

Comment: could you post what the a tag looks like in the browser?

Comment: like this gotten from inspect element?? <a xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" class="red_link" href="http://www-rainbowcode-mobi/view_message.php?id="><span class="red_link" id="td_subject">Freechat message 3</span></a>

Comment: that's odd... it looks like the variable is getting unset between echoing the input field and echoing the a tag... Is there any other code in your php file?

Comment: yes but all else works it is just getting the $new_id in to the a tag...it displays fine in the hidden input field then i echo it(added this line at top) then i have a tr tag then the a tag so 2 lines between hidden field and a tag...weird...